# how to make jupyter notebook and conda on local have the same env

Tags: tensorflow, path, jupyter-notebook, conda

I am facing an issue which I am having trouble solving.
I have installed conda. Using conda I installed tensorflow and keras. This was done using mac terminal and Anaconda GUI. It works fine.
I had jupyter notebook installed previously. When I try to import tensorflow on the notebook it fails.

I checked the system executables using `sys.executables` for both.
My macTerminal returns:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'/anaconda/bin/python'
```

My jupyter notebook returns:

```
Out[22]:
'/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7'
```

Clearly the paths are different. I would like to have my jupyter notebook reflect `/anaconda/bin/python` instead of the other path. I think this will make me be able to import tensorflow. But I am not able to do that, which is where I need help.

Comment: I solved it. I just added anaconda site packages to the pythonpath. The reason it still was not working after sourcing the bash is unknown. Restarting the system made it work.